# How to compare checked radio button to specific array value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms

(JavaScript and jQuery beginner--please be gentle.)

I'm trying to make my first JavaScript/jQuery app--a simple quiz with three questions, one button only, which outputs a final score at the end. I've got everything but the radio button checking--stumped. Can't figure out how to see if the checked radio button is the correct answer ('correctAnswer' in the initial array below). WOuld be grateful for any help.

QUIZ.JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var allQuestions = [
{question: "1: Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?", choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"], correctAnswer:0},
{question: "2: What is Barack Obama's middle name?", choices: ["Liberal", "Hussein", "Osama", "Joseph"], correctAnswer:1},
{question: "3: Who was President during the Civil War?", choices: ["Harry Truman", "John Tyler", "Abraham Lincoln", "John Adams"], correctAnswer:2}
];

var i = 0; //keep track of which question we're displaying.
var numCorrect = 0; // keep track of the number of correct answers.


    $("button").on('click',function(){  //when the button is clicked,

         // display the next question and all the possible answers...
         if (i < allQuestions.length) //if the question counter is less than the length of the array of answers...
           {
            $('#question').remove();  //remove the current question...
            $('.answerlist').remove();  //and remove the current list of answers...
            $('#questionhead').after('<p id="question">' + allQuestions[i]['question'] + '</p>'); //display the current question
            $('#answerhead').after("<form id='answerform'>");

            // display all the answers for the current question
            for (q=0; q < allQuestions[i]['choices'].length; q++){
               $('#answerform').after("<div class='answerlist'> <input type='radio' name='" +  allQuestions[i]['choices'][q]  +  "'>" + allQuestions[i]['choices'][q] + '<br /></div>');
               }
            $('button').before("</form>");

           i += 1;

           } else {
           $('#questionhead').remove();
           $('#answerhead').remove();
           $('#question').remove();  //remove the current question...
           $('.answerlist').remove();  //and remove the current list of answers...
           $('button').before('<h3>Final score:</h3> You got ' + numCorrect + ' out of 3 questions correct.');
           $('button').remove();
            }
    });

});
```

And the HTML page:

```
<html>

  <head>

    </head>

 <body>
<h1>JavaScript Quiz</h1>
<hr>


<h2 id = "questionhead">Question</h2>

<h2 id="answerhead">Answer</h2>

<p></p>
<button type = "button">Next Question</button>

<!-- Best practice: Load javascript file and jQuery at bottom of page, just before <body> tag. -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="quiz.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

Here's the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9pjW6/

Comment: If I may offer a suggestion, I think it would be better to store the associated text of each radio input as its 'value' attribute rather than as its 'name' attribute. Each radio input in a group of answers should have the same 'name' attribute - this will allow the user to select only one answer from the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put a data-id attribute to your inputs and check if the selected input data-id matches your correct answer number. Something like:

```
$("button").on('click',function(){

       if($("input:checked").length){
           if($("input:checked").attr("data-id")==allQuestions[i-1].correctAnswer){
               numCorrect+=1;
           }
       }

if (i < allQuestions.length) {

 //etc
for (q=0; q < allQuestions[i]['choices'].length; q++){
               $('#answerform').after("<div  class='answerlist'> <input data-id='"+q+"' type='radio' name='" +  allQuestions[i]['choices'][q]  +  "'>" + allQuestions[i]['choices'][q] + '<br /></div>');
 }
//etc

}
```

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/6TUYM/2/

Comment: Great--I see what you mean, thank you. When I run your code, though, the score's correct if one is correct, if two is correct--but never if three are correct. I must have a counter problem somewhere...

Comment: Works! Many thanks! And that helped me understand the concept a bit better, too.